# Falcon 9 altitude and speed during reentry burn?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, launch-sequence, entry-descent-landing

After MECO, stage 1 of Falcon 9 does up to three engine burns: a boostback burn followed by a reentry burn followed by a final landing burn.

I'm interested here in the reentry burn. How high and how fast is stage 1 going when it begins the reentry burn? How high and how fast when it ends the burn? How long does the burn last?

Comment: See [this flightclub.io-based answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49552/12102) which provides some pretty close simulations based on those SpaceX videos where we can also see this information for each launch. I think an answer to this question can pull a few screenshots and compile the numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @uhoh! I'll check it out. I keep forgetting about flightclub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search on YouTube
"SpaceX NROL" then you get videos like this one

The video only contains first stage recordings.

When the engines start:

- T + 6:30 min
- 58.1 km
- 4,757 km/h

When the engines stop:

- T + 6:58 min
- 31.1 km
- 2,245 km/h

Then the speed increases until:

- T + 7:12 min
- 21.9 km
- 2,495 km / h

Then the speed decreases from the friction with the more thick atmosphere until the landing burn starts at:

- T + 7:47 min
- 4.6 km
- 1,102 km / h

Touchdown at T + 8:18 min

Similar question:

[What is the return speed of the Falcon 9 booster?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/what-is-the-return-speed-of-the-falcon-9-booster)

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you, @JoeJobs! I've watched launch videos but hadn't noticed this info before. This is great. Thanks for sharing.