# Why does the Falcon 9 come back to the launch pad despite having considerable speed after boost back burn after separation?

Tags: falcon-9, trajectory

After separation, the first stage of a Falcon 9 makes a boost back burn.  When watching the webcast of the NROL 108 mission, after boost back it has a speed of 830 km/h at an altitutde of 148 km, then it gains more speed and decreasing altitude. That means the vertical speed reaches a value of zero but still has an 830 km/h horizontal speed. How it can come back to the landing pad near the launch pad? Shouldn't it go far away?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but similar https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59561/why-does-the-falcon-9-first-stage-continue-to-decelerate-after-its-reentry-engin

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing an image from Hobbes' answer to [What is the burn time for the F9 boostback / reentry / landing burns?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13708/22816)

[image]

The feed shows speed, but not direction.  By the time the booster reaches its peak altitude, it is already moving back towards the launch site.